# Different format outputs between python 3.3.4 and python 3.2.3

Tags: python, string-formatting

So I have typed a small script to print the multiplication tables up to 12, in python3.

The code I have tried are as follows:

```
def form(product):
    return "{:>4}".format(product)


count = 1
while (count < 13):
    for i in range(1,13):
        if i == 12:
            print(form(i*count))
        else: print(form(i*count), end=" ")
    count += 1
```

I have also tried this without the separate form function; adding everything within the print function. The output on my local computer (running python 3.3.4) is:

```
 1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12
 2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16   18   20   22   24
 3    6    9   12   15   18   21   24   27   30   33   36
 4    8   12   16   20   24   28   32   36   40   44   48
 5   10   15   20   25   30   35   40   45   50   55   60
 6   12   18   24   30   36   42   48   54   60   66   72
 7   14   21   28   35   42   49   56   63   70   77   84
 8   16   24   32   40   48   56   64   72   80   88   96
 9   18   27   36   45   54   63   72   81   90   99  108
10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90  100  110  120
11   22   33   44   55   66   77   88   99  110  121  132
12   24   36   48   60   72   84   96  108  120  132  144
```

Curious enough when I paste my script code into code_eval's python 3.2.3 interpreter I get this output:

```
 1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12
     2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16   18   20   22   24
     3    6    9   12   15   18   21   24   27   30   33   36
     4    8   12   16   20   24   28   32   36   40   44   48
     5   10   15   20   25   30   35   40   45   50   55   60
     6   12   18   24   30   36   42   48   54   60   66   72
     7   14   21   28   35   42   49   56   63   70   77   84
     8   16   24   32   40   48   56   64   72   80   88   96
     9   18   27   36   45   54   63   72   81   90   99  108
    10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90  100  110  120
    11   22   33   44   55   66   77   88   99  110  121  132
    12   24   36   48   60   72   84   96  108  120  132  144
```

As far as I can tell it's somehow not formatting the first iteration in my loop/while block. There must be something I'm missing in the documentation between those to python iterations. I am brand new to this as well so I am not sure what's missing at this point.

Comment: I got twice the same output for versions 3.2.4 and 3.3.2+.

Comment: Hmm well then I'm really unsure of why this is happening... You ran this in code_eval too?

Comment: No, I run it from the shell. (cython)